# Telnet honeypot errors

Tags: python, django, iot, malware, honeypot

root@honeypot:~/telnet-iot-honeypot# python backend.py

Creating/Connecting to DB
DB Setup done
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C

root@honeypot:~/telnet-iot-honeypot# python honeypot.py

2018-03-01 08:50:39   telnet.py:57      Socket open on port 23
2018-03-01 08:50:57   telnet.py:72      Client connected at ('[REDACTED]', 59542)
2018-03-01 08:50:57   session.py:22     New Session
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/telnet.py", line 75, in handle
 sess.loop()
 File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/telnet.py", line 96, in loop
 self.session = Session(self.send_string, self.remote[0])
 File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/session.py", line 26, in __init__
 self.record      = SessionRecord()
  File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/sampledb_client.py", line 51, in __init__
self.back    = get_backend()
File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/sampledb_client.py", line 14, in      get_backend
if _BACKEND:
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable '_BACKEND' referenced before assignment

https://github.com/Phype/telnet-iot-honeypot
This honeypot is used to monitor port 23 or 2223 for incoming connections. I am getting this error whenever a client connects. How do I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/Phype/telnet-iot-honeypot/issues/11

Comment: I get: root@honeypot:~/telnet-iot-honeypot# python honeypot.py           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "honeypot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from honeypot.telnet      import Telnetd
  File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/telnet.py", line 6, in <module>
    from session import Session
  File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sampledb_client import SessionRecord
  File "/root/telnet-iot-honeypot/honeypot/sampledb_client.py", line 18
    elif config.get("backend", optional=True) != None:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I get this new error when I change the sampledb_client.py in 
github.com/Phype/telnet-iot-honeypot/issues/11

Comment: The suggested fix for that specific issue would be to replace `tree = parse(l)` with `tree = run(l)` inside session.py

Comment: I'm still getting the error above about the syntax error even when i change the session.py file correctly.